# ALAssetsLibrary return two duplicated images (possible second one is HDR) with different URL

Tags: ios, iphone

I get a list of images by code bellow, but system return two duplicates with different URI. How I can avoid duplicates there?

```
NSMutableArray* assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if (!_library) _library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(result != nil) {
        if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto]) {
            [assetURLDictionaries addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];

            NSURL *url= (NSURL*) [[result defaultRepresentation]url];
            NSDate * date = [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
            if (url && date) [_imagesArray addObject:@{@"url":url,@"date":date}];
        } 
    }
};

NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

void (^ assetGroupEnumerator) ( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)= ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if(group != nil) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        [assetGroups addObject:group];
        count=[group numberOfAssets];
    } else {
        [_imagesArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]]];
    }
};


[_library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {NSLog(@"There is an error");}];
```